# Gpg4win keys stuck on failing Windows 10 HDD. What files do I need to extract before it stops working?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, gnupg, gpg4win

My friend's computer was not booting past the bios. He asked me to check it out. I tried to use a recovery USB but sadly chkdsk shows that there are way too many failing sectors on that disk.

Booting into Linux via a USB I can mount the HDD and extract some files. The main things he needs are some documents and his keys from Kleopatra (gpg4win).

Main question is:
*What files do I need to extract from the Windows FS so that he can import his keys on his new pc?*

He knows the passwords for all his keys.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to back up the whole directory at `%AppData%\gnupg`. It contains all of their private keys (in `private-keys-v1.d/`) as well as any imported public keys.